# Why does Twitter Bootstrap disable gradients for IE right after defining them?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap version 2.2.0 specifies the following CSS rules for `.btn`

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
```

Why does it disable the filter, right after it has been applied? If I look at the Bootstrap homepage in IE7 and IE9 I can see that the buttons don't have gradients on them. Why did they bother defining a gradient at all?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap now uses [Less](http://lesscss.org/) instead of plain CSS. My guess would be that they are using a mixin to generate cross-browser gradients, hence the first line.

The proprietary `filter` doesn't play well with `border-radius` (only an issue in IE9+ which supports both), so they disable the filter in those browsers, hence the over-ride in the second line.

Comment: The mixins are defined by Bootstrap themselves; I guess the mixins may be fully-inclusive so they can be used cross-browser in general, but the IE8/9 issue means they need to removed in this specific case.

Comment: @Steve - yep, that's what I was getting at. They presumably decided that it's simpler to just over-ride the generic mixin rather than create a new one excluding old IE.